# Separate folder for Api controllers and View controllers in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, .net-6.0

I am trying to take an existing .NET 6 ASP.NET Core project and separate out some of the data logic from the view logic. I have a bunch of view controllers that are also filled with data endpoints that I would like to move out to separate controllers. I am attempting to do this incrementally (since it is a large project) without having to do a full conversion.

The end goal is to shrink the size of the view controllers and combine some of the shared endpoints among the view controllers so that data comes specifically from an api endpoint not the root endpoint the views controllers are routing.

The folder structure I am trying to get to work currently is something like this:

```
Controllers
-> Api
--> Data1Controller
-> View1Controller
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to get the routing setup for all controllers in Api subfolder.

Edit:

I tried using Areas to do this and still wasn't able to get it to work:

routing code in program.cs:

```cs
app.UseRouting();
app.MapAreaControllerRoute("Api", "Api", "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
```

I set up a simple controller (DataController) with Api Area and /api/data returns 404

Comment: Are you perhaps conflating folders containing code and the URL to access the endpoint through HTTP?

Comment: I added some clarification, I am trying to set up the routing to have a api/ route that uses the controllers in the api/ subfolder. The mapping between the two is the goal I wish to achieve

Comment: Can you show your routing code?

Comment: I added what I have tried with code from my program.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just keep

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

add`[Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{id?}")]` on your api controller and it would work well.

I tested as below:
[image]

Also,you could try with

```
 app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "~/api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        new { controller = "...", action = "...." });
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to have `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]/{id?}")]` on every controller in my api folder?

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it

Comment: while the updated part might work, I wanted some to only be accessed via api/controller (specified by living in the api folder) and some to live /controller (everything else).

I ended up using inheritance to have a base class with the specified route pattern and all the other api classes inherit from it thus limited to that path.

Comment: Is there a way you could share a working example of your setup? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to revist this post to share what my setup ended up being:

I made an abstract controller `ApiBaseController` to help apply the `/Api` route to everything in my `/Controllers/Api` folder, now this solution doesn't make it just by having the controller in the `/Controllers/Api` folder but it does make it so I don't have to manually specify the path on each endpoint or each controller.

On the base controller, I added the route Attribute to the class itself:

```cs
[Route("/Api/[controller]/[action]")]
public abstract class ApiBaseController : ControllerBase { }
```

Then, each controller I have in the Api folder I inherit from that class:

```cs
public class DataController : ApiBaseController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Data()
  {
    return new JsonResult(new {id=1});
  }
}
```

This allows me to not specify routes for every api controller but just add inheritance to the abstract class. In the above example, the route is `/Api/Data/Data` and all my other controllers not inheriting from `ApiBaseController` use the default route setup by using `app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();`